# How to manage widget in row(flutter) one to the left and another one to the right

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout

```
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.money_rounded,size: 30,),
                      Text('เงินสด',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey[700],
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text('1000 THB',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey[700],
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                        onPressed: (){

                        },
                        child: Icon(Icons.add_outlined),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
```

according to the code, they sperate all widget in this row equally(bc MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround) like this 
----------------------------------------------
|...icon...|...text...|...text...|..button..|
----------------------------------------------
but i want to group first icon and first text to the left and other two to the right of this row.
like this

---------------------------------------------
| icon | text |..............|text| button |
---------------------------------------------
sorry, I cann't draw it so I hope you know what I want to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place `Spacer()` widget between them and that will do the trick.